# Why wouldn't this proof be correct for ℘(A ∪ B) = ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B) ↔ (A ⊂ B) ∨ (B ⊂ A) ∨ (A = B)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let U={1, 2, 3, ... 24, 25, 26, a, b, c, ... x, y, z}, A = {1, 2, 3, ... 24, 25, 26} and B = {a, b, c ... x, y, z}, then

→ A ∪ B = U

→ U ⊆ A ∪ B    Definition of a union

→ U ∈ ℘(A ∪ B)     Definition of a Power Set

However,  U ⊈ A ∧ U ⊈ B

→ U ∉ ℘(A) ∧ U ∉ ℘(B)      Definition of Union & Power Set

→ ~(U ∈ ℘(A) ∨ U ∈ ℘(B))  DeMorgan's Law

→ U ∉ ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B)     Definition of Union & Power Set

→ ℘(A ∪ B) ⊈ ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B)  Definition of a subset

∴ ℘(A ∪ B) ≠ ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B)

However, Let U, A and B be arbitrary sets, then

→ U ⊆ A ∪ B     Definition of a union

→ U ∈ ℘(A ∪ B)     Definition of a Power Set

Then Let (A ⊂ B) ∨ (B ⊂ A) ∨ (A = B)

→ U ⊆ A ∨ U ⊆ B (Definition of Union & Power Set)

→ U ⊆ A ∪ B (Definition of Union)

→ U ∈ ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B) (Definition of Union & Power Set)

∴ ℘(A ∪ B) = ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B) ↔ (A ⊂ B) ∨ (B ⊂ A) ∨ (A = B)

Comment: Because you forgot the twice other way round (that $P(A \cup B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$) and the $\Rightarrow$ part of you proof.

Comment: I have added the requested information into the proof section.

Comment: Note that in your example, if numbers are distinct from letters, then the set $\{1,2,3,a,b,c\}$ is a member of $\mathscr P(A\cup B)$ but is not a member of $\mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$. What makes this possible is that that are some things, namely $1,2,3$, that are members of $A$ and not of $B$, and some things, namely $a,b,c$, that are members of $B$ and not of $A$. As far as the proof goes, asking why it would NOT be a proof is putting the burden in the wrong place. Maybe you need to start from scratch on what proofs are.  The argument you wronte is just a mass of confusion.

Comment: I have changed the proof, to hopefully read as I intend.

Comment: I do not see how the final line foolish from any of the previous lines.  You haven't stated either statement at all and haven't shown how one statement would imply the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let U, A and B be arbitrary sets"

If $A, B$ and $U$ are arbitrary why are you introducing $U$.  If $U$ is arbitrary, then it isn't mentioned in the statement at all.

" then

→ A ∪ B = U "

If $A \cup B = U$ then $U$ is not an arbitrary set.  You need to have this as a premise and not as a result.

You should have said "Let $U = A \cup B$ then..."

"→ U ⊆ A ∪ B Definition of a union"

This isn't the definition of a union but basic property of sets.  $S \subseteq S$ for all sets so $U \subseteq U = A \cup B$.

" → U ∈ ℘(A ∪ B) Definition of a Power Set "

This isn't so much the definition as a consequence of identity.  $S \subseteq S$ for all sets so $S \in P(S)$ so $U \in P(U) = P(A\cup B)$.

Now at this point it isn't clear whether you have intended to have completed half of a two directional proof or are just starting a single direction.

"Then Let (A ⊆ B) ∨ (B ⊆ A) ∨ (A = B)"

Those are 3 conditionals you can not assume all of them at once.  $A\subseteq B$ OR $B\subseteq A$ OR $(A= B)$.

"→ U ∈ ℘(A) ∪ U ∈ ℘(B)"

This is either wrong or meaningless.

It's not really okay to write $R \in S \in T$ but, I suppose many people can use it as shorthand to mean $R \in S$ and $S \in T$.  If that is what you meant:

$U \not \in P(A) \cup U$ and $P(A) \cup U \not \in P(B)$.

$U \in P(A)$ only if $U \subset A$ but $U = A \cup B$ so $U \not \subset A$ unless $B \subset A=U$.  $U \not \in U$ as we are using set axioms that do not allow sets to be elements of themselves.

$P(A) \cup U \in P(B)$ means that $P(A) \subset B$ and $U \subset B$.  $U \not \subset B$ unless $A \subset B = U$.  $P(A) \subset B$ means $B$ includes all the subsets of $A$ including $A$ itself.  THis could be true but we have utterly no reason to think it would be.  If it were than $A \not \subset B = U$ as our set axioms won't allow that.

"→ U ⊆ A ∨ U ⊆ B (Definition of Union & Power Set)"

This just isn't true at all.  $U = (A \cup B) \not subset A$ (unless $B \subset A$ nor is $U = (A \cup B) \not \subset B$ (unless $A \subset B$).

"→ U ⊆ A ∪ B (Definition of Union)"

You already stated this and this is certainly *NOT* the definition of union.

"→ U ∈ ℘(A ∪ B) (Definition of Power Set) "

You already stated this.

"∴ ℘(A ∪ B) = ℘(A) ∪ ℘(B) ↔ (A ⊆ B) ∨ (B ⊆ A) ∨ (A = B)"

Why?  I don't see how any of this follows.  You've stated $A\cup B \in P(A\cup B)$ (which is obvious) and nothing about $P(A) \cup P(B)$.

=====

My advise:

Don't introduce $U = A\cup B$.  It adds nothing to your proof and it lead you on some *very* false roads.

Note: if $A \subseteq B$ then $S \subset A \implies S \subset B$.  So $(A \subset B) \lor (B \subset A) \lor (A =B) \implies P(A\cup B)= P(A) \cup P(B)$ should be obvious.

Note: if neither $A \subseteq B$ nor $B\subseteq A$ then there are $a \in A; b \in B; a \not \in B; b \not \in A$.

So the set $\{a,b\} \subset A\cup B$  so $\{a,b\} \in P(A\cup B)$.  But $\{a,b\} \not \subset A$ and $\{a,b\} \not \subset B$.  So $\{a,b\} \not \in P(A) \cup P(B)$.

Comment: Yes, this is half of a two directional proof.  I was using this for my homework, however I just couldn't figure out how to get it to work.  I have been working on it for a week, and now have no more time.  I couldn't figure out how to put it into proof.  I am still working on it even though it is too late to turn in.  This is very interesting to me.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added the rest of my proof.  If you could please take another look and let me know if this is now correct, I would be very appreciative.